# How do I use Servlet 3.0 Async Methods in Dropwizard?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, jersey, servlet-3.0, dropwizard

I have a resource method that looks like this:

```
@Path("hard")
@GET
public Response sayHello2(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
        throws InterruptedException {
    AsyncContext ac = request.startAsync();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    ac.complete();

    return Response.ok("hello world hard").build();
}
```

It looks like the code runs through, but I can't seem to verify that async is working in this case? Am I using this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have no dropwizard experience but in an async servlet you shouldn't block the servlet thread with a thread sleep. You can use an ExecutorService in your servlet to delegate the work to another thread after calling request.startAsync(). You should pass the async context to you worker thread and when that finished it calls ac.complete().